# How can i take this number in python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

[photo of css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHKWP.png)

my code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    score = response.css('div.twoRowExtra')

    for match in match:

        score1 = score.css('div.livescore.twoRowExtraRow:first-child span::text').extract()

        items['score1'] = score1


        yield items
```

always response is score1:[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function out:

```
def parse(self, response):
    score = response.css('div.twoRowExtra')

    for match in score:
        score1 = match.css('div.livescore.twoRowExtraRow:first-childspan::text').extract()
        items['score1'] = score1
        yield items
```

Comment: Check that and if not run successfully then tell me what's the error

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please check [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.